# Changes to Solr schema.xml do not update after stoping and restarting Solr

Tags: solr

I am a new learner of Solr. Now I want to make my own schema.xml. So I add some fields. I stop the solr and restart it. In the admin of solr, I can see the changes in the schema choice. But the content of schema browser doesn't changes. And when I want to index some document. There is an error that says there is no field which I just added in the schema. The content of schema browser is not same as the schema file.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually updating the correct schema.xml file? From your description (and that the schema browser doesn't show the version you think it should show) it seems you're not editing the actual file. Reloading the core should also be enough - you don't need to restart the whole application server.

Comment: I am sure I modify the correct schema.xml. Because somethimes I can add a new field, but most of time, it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

Changing the schema of a core doesn't change the documents you already have there, which is why they look the same even after you restart the Solr service. You need to re-upload the documents with the new fields specified (if they are `required` fields) after you make a schema change to get these new fields for existing documents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I re-upload the documents? I use sunburnt to communicate with solr. The problem is, every time I run si.add(doc),(doc is a python dictionary), it reply can not find the field, but the field is already add in the schema.xml

Comment: I've never used sunburnt, but that error suggests you haven't successfully changed the schema. Ditto your comment that the schema browser shows something different. Try a full Tomcat restart (which I presume you are using, **careful to make sure your cores persist before you do a restart if they have valuable data!**), and see if that updates what you see in the schema browser.

Answer (score 0):

[image: solr dashboard]

from here I went to the path of my core instance to make the changes.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/solr@7.7/7.7.3_1/server/solr/drupal
```

then I was able to confirm the changes by clicking on Files and scrolling to where I made the change.

[image: solr files]